# React | Synthetic Event interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### TLDR

> What is `bubbles`, `cancelable`, `defaultPrevented`, `eventPhase`, `isTrusted`, `timestamp`, `type` in SyntheticEvent and how can I use it

### Answer

Hello, I'm react and react native developer.
When I studied about `SyntheticEvent` in react today, I had a question about this interface `SyntheticEvent`

```js
boolean bubbles
boolean cancelable
DOMEventTarget currentTarget
boolean defaultPrevented
number eventPhase
boolean isTrusted
DOMEvent nativeEvent              // I know it is original browser dom event
void preventDefault()             // I know it is for prevent element basic event like a tag
boolean isDefaultPrevented()      // I guess it is for knowing is preventDefault() is executed 
void stopPropagation()            // I know it is for stop event bubbling and capturing
boolean isPropagationStopped()    // I guess it is for knowing is stopPropagation() is executed
void persist()                    // It is for persist synthetic event pooling
DOMEventTarget target             // I know target means dom event target like 
number timeStamp
string type
```

So at this situation, I have no idea what is `bubbles`, `cancelable`, `defaultPrevented`, `eventPhase`, `isTrusted`, `timestamp`, `type` and how can we use this interface.

Is there any good use case with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these are inherited from native `Event`.

You can read about them [in the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

You can also read about specific `SyntheticEvent` stuff [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Comment: Oh, Thanks to you, I can know about native event.
but if it's okay with you, do you happen to know How to use it or use case?

Comment: For `bubbles` and `eventPhase`, check this out https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow .
`defaultPrevented` is used to check if `preventDefault` was called on the event.
`type` is the... type (name) of the event.
Everything is explained in the docs!

Comment: Oh Thank you so much!